# %thread and duplicate thread names

Tags: logstash-logback-encoder

I have run into issues with 3rd party libraries and threads using the same name.  Is there a way to show a hash or unique id for the thread?

I ended up creating my own converter to handle it, I wasn't sure if I was missing something.

Here's what I have

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.pattern.ClassicConverter;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;

/**
 * Creates a hash string for the current thread
 */
@Component
public class ThreadHashHexString extends ClassicConverter {
  @Override
  public String convert(ILoggingEvent event) {
    return Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(Thread.currentThread()));

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, logback only captures the thread name in its [`LoggingEvent`](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/7ee74ad132bf74ead68c5bb553f5353aa2588bb0/logback-classic/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/classic/spi/LoggingEvent.java#L63). i.e. logback does *not* capture the thread id or any other information about the thread that logged the event.

The problem with your proposed solution is that it assumes the current thread is the thread on which the `LoggingEvent` was generated, which will not always be the case.  For example, if an asynchronous appender is used, the current thread on which the converter is called will be the thread that encodes the event, not the thread that logged the event.

If you are *not* using an asynchronous appender, then you can use `Thread.currentThread()` in a converter as you have done.  Or (since you tagged the question with logstash-logback-encoder), you could implement your own [`JsonProvider`](https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder/blob/e35a4dcd2d3220f9f78359fbe1be9eb2d4576de0/src/main/java/net/logstash/logback/composite/JsonProvider.java) to log the thread id/identityHashCode as a JSON field.

Comment: Excellent point! But if we are only logging to stdout we should be good right?

Comment: As long as the console appender is not behind an asynchronous appender, it should be fine.